# How to pass a string inside double quote in C++

Tags: c++, string, double-quotes

Background:

I'm using Matlab with C++ for plotting purposes. In my present process, I need to pass a variable to matlab using matlab's function and also a string which will name the variable in matlab environment.  The function I'm calling is `engPutVariable(ep, "varMatlab" , varC++)` where ep is the object of class (matlab)Engine, `varC++` is the name of the variable inside C++ which I am passing and `varMatlab` will be the name of the same variable when is stored in matlab workspace. The process I use needs 4 lines of code to pass a single variable which does the same job for each variable I pass, hence I want to write a function which has the arguments of name of the variable in c++ and the name of the variable in matlab which needs to be in " " quotes.

Question:

As the function requires the name of the variable to be passed inside " " (double quotes),  I want to pass a string which will take the place of varMatlab inside the quotes. I tried using inserting the " " with the string itself but it seems that is not working in this case. Any help will be really helpful.

I wrote the following function to do the same but the string `name` should be inside the " " which I dont know how to pass.

```
void putVar(double* var,int N, string name, Engine *ep){
    double row = N, col = N;
    mxArray *matlab = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(row, col, mxREAL);
    double *pa = mxGetPr(matlab);
    memcpy(pa, var, sizeof(double)*row*col);
    engPutVariable(ep, "name" , matlab);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're confused about needing the quotes as part of the string. I think all you need is access to the c-string inside the C++ string. Get rid of the quotes and try `name.c_str()`.

Answer (score 2):

Insert the " as \". As " is a special symbol for strings, it needs to be escaped. So the string "Hello World" with the quotes looks like this in C++

```
std::cout << "\"Hello World\"\n";
```

Regards
Tobias

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean escaping?
The word "escaping" means in this context: You cannot use the character `"` as content of a string becauase it's part of the c++ language.

So you have to *escape* it in order to make the string literally contain `"name"`.
For this example, your code would look like this:

```
void putVar(double* var,int N, string name, Engine *ep){
    double row = N, col = N;
    mxArray *matlab = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(row, col, mxREAL);
    double *pa = mxGetPr(matlab);
    memcpy(pa, var, sizeof(double)*row*col);
    engPutVariable(ep, "\"name\"" , matlab);
}
```

Did I misunderstood you?